# Should I always return a JsonResult from controller when called via Ajax?

Tags: ajax, asp.net-mvc

If I call my MVC controller via Ajax, should the controller then as a rule always return a Json (JsonResult) or can it be a view (ViewResult) as well?

Comment: It doesn't need to be a Json, you can return a PartialViewResult which can be interpreted then in the browser as html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It can return either of them but a viewresult would typically be an html string while a json result would be json (native to javascript).

They are situations where you'll may need to return a view (if you need to update sections of your page)